# Voltage across capacitor in a electrical circuit (LCC circuit)

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis, passive-networks

My networkanalyses book told me that the voltage across the capacitor C2 is given by:

$$\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)+\text{C}_1\cdot\text{L}\cdot\text{U}_{\text{in}}''\left(t\right)-\text{L}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)$$

Where the network looks like:

[image]

And I want to know if it is correct and how they got it?!

---

**MY WORK:**

$$\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}_2=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{U}_{\text{L}}\left(t\right)\right)\cdot\text{C}_2=$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{I}_{\text{L}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\right)\cdot\text{C}_2=$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\right)\cdot\text{C}_2$$

So, we get:

$$\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}_2=\left(\text{U}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)-\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\right)\cdot\text{C}_2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}'\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)-\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}'\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t=\int\text{U}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t-\int\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\color{red}{\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}}$$

And knowing that:

$$\text{I}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{I}_{\text{C}_1}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{U}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}_1$$

We can write the red part:

$$\color{red}{\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\text{I}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\text{U}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}_1\right)\cdot\text{L}}=$$
$$\color{red}{\text{U}_{\text{C}_2}\left(t\right)=\text{U}_{\text{in}}\left(t\right)-\left(\text{I}_{\text{in}}'\left(t\right)-\text{U}_{\text{in}}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}_1\right)\cdot\text{L}}$$

Comment: As you ask the question right now, it's too broad – as you say, we'd need to write a complete linear network analysis pamphlet to answer your "how they got it" question. You should show what you've been able to calculate so far, and where you've got a result that doesn't agree with the book (otherwise, your "is this correct?" question makes no sense – we're not the free editing team for all EE books worldwide).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I edited my work into my question

Comment: The last red equation is the same as the book, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Chu Oh haha I see now, but I still don't know if my derivation is right?!